# Нужно найти всевозможное кол-во команд

Tags: python, комбинаторика

есть три команды:

1. Прибавить 1
2. Прибавить 2
3. Умножить на 2

Задача:
найти кол-во программ состоящих ровно из 6 команд которые число 1 преобразуют в 20.

Comment: Тут можно и простым перебором. Всего-то 729 комбинаций, из них 36 нужных.

Comment: желательно кодом бы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекурсией. https://ideone.com/RMbBHl

```
def do(x, level=6):
    return x == 20 if level == 0 else do(x+1, level-1) + do(x+2, level-1) + do(x*2, level-1)

print(do(1))
```

Перебором. https://ideone.com/rR9KjA

```
from itertools import product
count = 0
for ops in product([1,2,3], repeat=6):
    x = 1
    for op in ops:
        if op in [1,2]:
            x += op
        else:
            x *= 2
    if x == 20:
        count += 1
        #print(ops)
print(count)
```

Comment: Серьёзно, 36? UPDATE: Стоп, я неправ... Забыл про 6 действий.

Comment: Хотя асимптотика так себе.

Comment: Первый код прям красота. Коротко, понятно

Answer (score 4):

Нужная величина - сумма количества программ из ровно 5 команд, которые число 1 преобразуют в 19, 18, и в 10. Чувствуете, что рекурсия напрашивается?

Answer (score 2):

## Асимптотика *O(число*шаги)*

https://ideone.com/sxy0XC

```
n = 20
m = 6
s = 1

a = [[0 for c in range(m+1)] for i in range(n+1)]
a[s][0] = 1

for i,x in enumerate(a):
  for c,k in enumerate(x):
    if k and c<m:
      if i+1 <= n: a[i+1][c+1] += k
      if i+2 <= n: a[i+2][c+1] += k
      if i+i <= n: a[i+i][c+1] += k

print(a[n][m])
```

```
36
```

Весь a[n]:

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 13, 36]

#### Без ограничения количества действий за *O(число)*:

https://ideone.com/Y3n76v

```
n = 20
s = 1

a = [0] * (n+1)
a[s] = 1

for i,x in enumerate(a):
  if i+1 <= n: a[i+1] += x
  if i+2 <= n: a[i+2] += x
  if i+i <= n: a[i+i] += x

print(a[n])
```

```
20174
```

Весь список:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 20, 30, 57, 87, 154, 241, 415, 656, 1101, 1757, 2915, 4672, 7674, 12346, 20174]